# Java Map.containsValue doesn't work after 15000th item in the list

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two HashMaps and there are 30000 same words with different order in each of these lists. Although I can compare the search values coming from the second list by the first list, the comparison does not work after 15000th item. I know there is no guarantee in the hashmap, but I do not need order and I just check words in the search map by the list map and remove the founded words. If the list contains all the words in search, want to return true. Is there any point that I missed?

```
//Sample values (30000 same words with different order):
//list: hooef dalwm vuitg enewb xcbfy ...
//search: dalwm xcbfy hooef enewb dalwm ...

Map<Integer, String> list = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
Map<Integer, String> search = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
boolean check = true;

for(int i=0; i<search.size(); i++) {
    if(list.containsValue(search.get(i)))
        list.remove(i);
    else
        check = false; //when i=15000 the code hits to here
}
return check; //returns false
```

Comment: HashMaps have no order, does the Integer key represents the order of the words?

Comment: I assign the HashMap values from a string array using a loop. But I am not sure if the order is stable. On the other hand, I think the main point  causing the problem is `list.containsValue(search.get(i))`, because it removes a random element.

Comment: What about using `LinkedHashMap`? Can I make the orders are the same using it?

Comment: Seems like a case of XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. I suggest to edit your question with all the relevant information or delete it and create another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `containsValue` appeared not to work is that you had already inadvertently deleted the value it was looking for.

```
Assume Search -> 1:A, 2:B, 3:C
         List -> 3:B, 1:C, 2:A
```

`List` checks to see if it contains `Search's` value at key `1`. It does. It is at `key 2` in `List`.  But you delete key `1` at `List` thinking it was value `A`.  But it was value `C`.  Now when `List` checks for value `C`, it will fail.

As I see it you have three issues to contend with.

- You are trying to relate two maps that essentially have different key to value mappings (in spite of the fact they they have the same set of keys and values).
- You want to search and delete based on values and not keys.
- And that you can have duplicate values.

Here was my approach.  The first part is building the data structures for testing.

```
Stream<String> stream = null;
try {
    stream = Files.lines(Path.of("f:/linux.words"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// limit to 100_000 word
int count = 100_000;
```

Now ensure the words are in different order.

```
String[] words1 = stream.limit(count).toArray(String[]::new);
String[] words2 = words1.clone();
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(words2)); // shuffle the array.
```

Now build two different maps `search` and `list`

```
Map<Integer, String> list = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, String> search = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < words1.length; i++) {
    list.put(i + 1, words1[i]);
    search.put(i + 1, words2[i]);
}
```

Now create a `valueToKeyMap` that maps all values to their respective keys.  Since values can be duplicated the keys are contained in a `List`

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> valueToKeyMap = list.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue,
                Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey,
                        Collectors.toList())));
```

Now iterate thru the maps removing duplicates. The lists in the valueToKeyMap will need to be
iterated but it is expected (perhaps incorrectly) that the number of duplicates of any given string will be small (e.g. the word `cow` will only occur maybe 10 times).

This appears to work fairly fast.  The entire effort including file reading, etc takes about 1 second.  Part of that speed is due to the fact that there were no duplicates so each `List<Integer>` of `keys` was of length 1.

```
count = 0;
int size = list.size();
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    String value = search.get(i);
    if (valueToKeyMap.containsKey(value)) {
        // no need to verify if list contains value, valueToKeyMap was
        // created from it.
        for (int vkm : valueToKeyMap.get(value)) {
            list.remove(vkm);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(list);
System.out.println(list.size());
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot these wonderful explanations. Is there a way to remove an element by value from HashMap? If so, I can easily fix the problem by changing the ralated line.

Comment: Unfortunately not that I am aware.  That would have certainly simplified your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the key of the maps is the order, then `list.remove(i);` is removing a random value from `list`, which doesn't seem correct.

Here's a possible solution:

```
Collection<String> values = list.values(); 

for(int i=0; i<search.size(); i++) {
    if(!values.remove(search.get(i))) {
        check = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it takes too long time and causing timeout. Is there any way to solve that using Map?